# Does Apple’s Magic Trackpad put more stress on the hand, wrist and arm than a traditional mouse?

Tags: computers, repetitive-strain-injury

I have read and heard contradicting personal experiences on how much stress on the hand, wrist and arm [Apple's Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/) put compared to a traditional mouse.

E.g.

http://softwareprototyping.net/is-your-apple-magic-trackpad-giving-you-rsi/:

> I am starting to suffer from pain in my right hand which I am wondering might be due to the use of the Magic Trackpad.

http://erikrunyon.com/2011/01/rsi-and-the-magic-trackpad/ :

> Back to the question of RSI. After three months of use, I’ve noticed a significant decrease in pain

Does Apple’s Magic Trackpad put  more stress on the hand, wrist and arm than a traditional mouse?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have only anecdotal evidence; personally, I find the magic trackpad much better for most general purpose computing use and I believe it puts less strain on the whole lower arm structure. There are, however, certain tasks where I find using a mouse to be easier though, as I have now used the trackpad for some years and consequently become more adept, the difference is less marked than it was.

One would hope that an ergonomist might have carried out some research.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!